# A picture of a line

Tags: knowledge, lateral-thinking

Four Harvard students Bates, Denise, Dennis and Sacha had someone take a picture of them with all of them holding a specific drink in their hands. All four of them were also wearing the same type of shirt which had nothing but a large star figure printed on it. Before the picture of them was taken they made sure that the four of them arranged themselves in a line so that Denise was placed to the far left and the rest in some ordered way. This way the picture made perfect sense to them.

---

**How did they line up and what drink did they all hold in their hands? Explain your reasoning.**

Hint:

> The star on their shirts is a description of something geography related.

Comment: Are Denise and Dennis twins? <joke />

Comment: maybe, maybe not ;)

Comment: @Prim3numbah does the puzzle have something to do with Big Dipper?

Comment: @webadventurer No, nothing to do with that.

Comment: Do they all have the same drink?

Comment: @hexomino Yes, same drink

Comment: It might be worth posting a hint; I (and possibly other people) am still interested in this puzzle.

Comment: @TylerSelden Sure, I'll add a hint

Comment: Just a suspicion: rot13(gur fghqragf ner fbzr rkvfgvat crefbaf ng Uneineq naq unir gur ynfganzrf Abegu,Rnfg,Fbhgu,Jrfg. Guvf fubhyq tvir gur beqre. Naq gur fgne vf n pbzcnff ebfr. Ohg jung nobhg gur qevax? V qba'g xabj vs gurer vf nal pbpxgnvy be fbzr qevax eryngrq gb 'arfj' be 'arjf'.) But I cannot make sense out of it.

Comment: @theozh Not a bad idea but the star actually represents something else, so it's not related to cardinal directions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The students lined up (from left to right) as:

> Denise, Sacha, Dennis, Bates

The drink that they each held in their hands was:

> **Coca Cola**!

Because:

> The stars on their shirts represent **US states** (exactly like the stars on the US flag, and further being pointed to by these students being based in America at Harvard). Each of their names begins with 3 letters that also begin the name of a state capital: **Den**nis/**Den**ise = **Den**ver (Colorado CO), **Sac**ha = **Sac**ramento (California CA), and **Bat**es = **Bat**on Rouge (Louisiana LA).
>
>  If we take the **2-letter state abbreviations** for these states, then standing in these positions and reading them from left to right, their states spell out **CO-CA-CO-LA**! (They could perhaps be involved in a photoshoot for an advertisement...)

Comment: Got it, nice job :)